# Multiple themes in Magento 2.2 that extend off of each other?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, css, less, less-css

I've created a theme at:

```
app/design/frontend/<vendor>/default
```

That I call my "default" theme with some base styles, that inherit from Magento Blank as it's parent. Default just has universal styles that all of my other themes will use.

In the default theme, I'm using:

```
app/design/frontend/<vendor>/default/web/css/source/_extend.less
```

An `_extend.less` file to extend from the parent Magento Blank theme.

Now, I also have different stores in Magento, so building off of the default theme, I have:

```
app/design/frontend/<vendor>/shop1

app/design/frontend/<vendor>/shop2
```

And I'm seeing that if I put in an `_extend.less` into

```
app/design/frontend/<vendor>/shop1/web/css/source/_extend.less
```

That doesn't appear to be working. The shop1 theme is using default as it's parent, and is correctly inheriting the styles of default. However, shop1 is not being extended by any customizations that I'm placing into it's _extend.less file. Am I doing something wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: What are you customize? the .css files or .less or ...

Comment: @Prince The less files. I outlined that above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create new less file for your shop1 theme

> /app/design/frontend/Vendor/shop1/web/css/source/shop1.less

Override below file in your theme

> /vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/source/_sources.less

Import your less file in source.less

> /app/design/frontend/Vendor/shop1/web/css/source/_sources.less

Like this `@import '_shop1.less';`